# How to get the index of a record ordered by something in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Assume, I have student exam result set which is ordered by a point. I want to get the order index of a student in this result set. How can I get rid of that by using linq?

Assume the class like this;

```
class ExamResult
{
   int StudentId;
   int Point;
   int ExamId;
}

ExamId StudentId Point
 1        1       5,2
 1        2       5,4
 1        3       3
 1        4       7,2
 1        5       7,9
 1        6       1
 1        7       2,6
 1        8       6
 1        9       11
```

After I ordered the students by point. Student 2 has to be at index 5.

Comment: It's ordered by point? I don't get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using LINQ to Objects? If so, there's a [`Select` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) which gives you the index as well as the value. ([Ditto for `Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) and probably others too.) The `Select` overload therefore makes it easy to transform the original value into "original value + index" as an anonymous type.

Your question wasn't entirely clear - if this wasn't what you're after, perhaps you could give some sample code?